# How do I apply mdbootstrap to my vue project?

Tags: vue.js, mdbootstrap

I'm new to Vue.js and have just started learning it by myself. 
The first thing I wanted to try was using MDBootstrap's login template to my project.

https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/jquery/forms/basic/

I copied codes by clicking 'copy code' from the above link, and have downloaded mdbootstrap.zip, upzipped it and placed it in my project.

The copied code is saved with name 'Login.vue', and is properly exported and properly referenced by 'App.vue' file.

However the Login page I wanted never shows up. I guess I omitted some 'import' or '' that should be included to activate mdbootstrap functionality?

Comment: [MDBootstrap for Vue](https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/vue/), perhaps? Here's the deal: without *search-fu*, forget about coding. Nobody can code without it. Seriously.

Comment: Thanks for the kind recommendation. I've also come across that one, but I guess I was in a hurry.

Comment: You're quite welcome, Kim. Happy coding!